# How can I use functional time series or functional principal component regression for forecasting this type of data?

Tags: forecasting, functional-data-analysis

[image: Functional data series]

Lets say I have this type of data. For one of the series, I observed data until day 300. Can I use functional principal component regression to forecast next 50 observations? What is the best way to use partially observed data for one of the curves to predict where the curve will go?

Comment: See https://doi.org/10.1016/j.matcom.2010.04.027

Comment: Thank you prof. Hyndman. Exactly what I was looking for